# Omnet++ double variable error

Tags: double, omnet++

I want to calculate the double value in omnet and everything is defined in double to calculate remaining energy of sensor node.But it calculates the energy level in integer format. So I cannot see the double value. It decrements the energy by 1, but it should be decremented 0.000538.

For example if initial energy is 10, I should see the remaining 10 - 0.000538, but I saw it 9.Thus our results is incorrect. How can I solve this problem?

```
lcnBtrySt = (double)getParentModule()->par("lcnBat_Full")

//lcnBtrySt is reached from the network.ned file.

//When I append the .DOUBLE to end of the
```

`(double)getParentModule()->par("lcnBat_Full").DOUBLE`,

```
//its energy starts from 67.But actual one is 110160 j.
//I cannot fix the problem.


Rx value = 0.000538 ,hopBits =10.0;

    ev<<"Rx is equal to ",lcnBtrySt=lcnBtrySt-(Rx*hopBits);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please don't add "urgent" shouting anywhere in your posts, especially titles.

Answer (score 1):

In general, do not cast return values (by writing `(double)foo`). This will hide any errors that might occur: it forces the compiler to accept whatever you are trying to assign - no matter whether s is actually a good idea.

Use `par("foo").doubleValue()` to read a parameter's value as a double.

Comment: Thanks four your help @Christoph Sommer .But it does not shown expected value. I need to see 110160-0.000538 =110159.999462.It always decremented by 1.  110159, 110158 I am at stuck please help me.

Comment: The line `Rx value = 0.000538 ,hopBits =10.0;` looks strange. Can you try simplifying your example further?